# SaxonJS in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, saxon-js

I'm having trouble importing SaxonJS to NodeJS application.

```js
const saxonJs = require("saxon-js");

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(saxonJs));
// [ ]

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window.SaxonJS));

/**
[
      'atom',              'Atomic',
      'transform',         'Serializer',
      'serialize',         'StringWriter',
      'getProcessorInfo',  'getResource',
      'setLogLevel',       'getLogLevel',
      'setPlatform',       'getPlatform',
      'getNavigator',      'timeStamp',
      'internalTransform', 'checkOptions',
      'makeAtomicValue',   'getItemDetails',
      'XdmArray',          'XdmFunction',
      'XdmMap',            'U',
      'XError',            'XPath',
      'XS',                'Developer'
    ]
    */

const testOutput = saxonJs.transform({
                    stylesheetFileName: xslt_filepath,
                    sourceFileName: source_filename,
                    destination: 'raw',
                });
// returns TypeError: saxonJs.transform is not a function

window.SaxonJS.transform({
                    stylesheetFileName: xslt_filepath,
                    sourceFileName: inputFiles[j],
                    destination: 'raw',
                });
// XError: Cannot supply stylesheetFileName in browser
```

returns TypeError: saxonJs.transform is not a function

what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error and was able to resolve it by adding the below to my package.json file. This makes Jest use node environment instead of the jsdom (default):

`"jest": { "testEnvironment": "node" }`

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
require('SaxonJS2N.js')
```

I think you've picked up the browser version of Saxon-JS rather than the Node.js version.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but it didn't make any difference. In package.json of `saxon-js`, it seems that main file being imported is actually `SaxonJSN.js`. 

Could you be kind to explain how `SaxonJSN.js` determine whether it is running from browser or node.js?

I'm running the code inside `jest` testing framework to transform xml and validate them with expected output. Perhaps it's something I need to configure from testing framework.

Comment: This is turning into more of a support ticket than a simple question-and-answer, so I suggest you raise it as a Saxon-JS enquiry on saxonica.plan.io. We haven't done any testing under jest so this will need some investigation. It would be a good idea if you raise a ticket to tell us exactly what we need to do to reproduce the problem.